# How to transform the values from logical memory to the physical memory. (Paging)

Tags: operating-system, paging

And then I was given that Page size = 4 bytes, Physical memory =40 bytes. There were two tables, one being the page table with 4 pages ranging from 0-3 and the other being the logical memory table with 15 rows corresponding to alphabets.The link contains a image of the question[text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am5by.jpg).Any help regarding this quesstion would be really appreciated.

So I was absent when they taught this in my uni and they didnt even explain how to do this in the pdf they gave us and the friends I know in uni also couldnt understand it apparently. I do know most of the theory. I just dont know any equations or whatever I need to do this question